# How is the return method used in iterators / async iterators?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-iterator

[MDN states that async iterators have a return method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

```js
const asyncIterable = {
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    let i = 0;
    return {
      next() {
        const done = i === LIMIT;
        const value = done ? undefined : i++;
        return Promise.resolve({ value, done });
      },
      return() {
        // This will be reached if the consumer called 'break' or 'return' early in the loop.
        return { done: true };
      }
    };
  }
};
```

However, the Typescript definitions of async iterators require the `return` method to

1. accept an optional value
2. return `{value: someValue, done: true}`, whereas MDN does not do this.

Here's the TS definition:

```
interface AsyncIterator<T, TReturn = any, TNext = undefined> {
    // NOTE: 'next' is defined using a tuple to ensure we report the correct assignability errors in all places.
    next(...args: [] | [TNext]): Promise<IteratorResult<T, TReturn>>;
    return?(value?: TReturn | PromiseLike<TReturn>): Promise<IteratorResult<T, TReturn>>;
    throw?(e?: any): Promise<IteratorResult<T, TReturn>>;
}
```

Can someone explain the discrepancy? How does `return` work?

Comment: What discrepancy? The return method in your example _does_ accept an optional parameter, for example, it just _ignores_ it.

Comment: What does the optional parameter do, why is MDN ignoring it

Comment: The example from MDN returns an object with the necessary `done: true`; no `value` property means it will be read as `undefined`. This is mostly how JavaScript works.

Comment: I'm aware. My question is ... what happens if we don't ignore the `value` property? Will it do something ? Presumably the Typescript team made `value` an optional property for a reason.

Comment: You can observe the return value by using `yield*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MDN, however authoritative, is not the source of truth when it comes to language specifications. TypeScript follows the [ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/), in this instance, the definition of the [`AsyncIterator`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-asynciterator-interface) interface (as `@@asyncIterator` [well-known symbol](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-well-known-symbols) is a method that returns an `AsyncIterator`).

Table 76 and 77 of the spec provide, respectively, the required and optional properties of the interface: `next`, `return`, and `throw`. We are interested in what the spec has to say about the parameters of the second one:

> The returned promise will fulfill with an `IteratorResult` object which will typically have a "done" property whose value is true, and a "value" property **with the value passed as the argument of the return method. However, this requirement is not enforced.**

Note the last part of the first sentence — here is where the `TReturn | PromiseLike<TReturn>` comes from. Then note the second sentence — this is why the parameter is optional.

As you can also see from the above, the `return` method returns an object implementing the [`IteratorResult`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-iteratorresult-interface) interface which is defined to have a `done` boolean and a `value` unrestricted property. Both properties are not considered optional, but each has a note in table 78 of the spec that allows for either to be missing.

However, TypeScript definition for the `IteratorReturnResult` (a member of the `IteratorResult` union type) does not take into account those notes and marks those properties as required:

```js
interface IteratorReturnResult<TReturn> {
    done: true;
    value: TReturn;
}
```

This has been called into question in [issue #8938](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8938) on the source repository with the team reasoning being:

> As noted by @ivogabe we need to have boolean literal types, to be able to model this one accurately.

and subsequently closed in favor of [issue #2983](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2983) fixed by [PR #30790](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30790) with the original request seemingly slipping through the cracks.